Breaking Down Transaction Table
My table transation consists of tranxid, custid, itemid, quantity, unit_price, payment mode, driverid.
When I perform add operations and notice that customer 1 can buy at least one or two items more and so on. There is some duplication for the custid, itemid, driverid and payment mode. How can I resolve this duplications?
Can I use the one to many/many to one relationship to split the transaction table into two table?


tranxid, custid, itemid, quantity, unit_price, payment mode, driverid.
There is some duplication for the custid, itemid, driverid and payment mode.

It sounds like your Customer can place an Order for multiple Items.
In that case, you need two tables, one to represent the overall Order and another to represent the individual Items within that Order.
select * 
from orders ; 

+---------+--------+----------+--------------+
| TRANXID | custid | driverid | payment_mode | 
+---------+--------+----------+--------------+
|     123 |    345 |      456 |         VISA |
+---------+--------+----------+--------------+

select * 
from order_lines ; 

+---------+--------+----------+------------+
| TRANXID | ITEMID | quantity | unit_price | 
+---------+--------+----------+------------+
|     123 |    567 |        1 |       1.99 |
|     123 |    678 |        2 |       2.99 |
+---------+--------+----------+------------+

